Why is it said that magnetometer calibration mitigates soft iron effects?
I've seen it written in many places (for example Matlab's magcal) that magnetometer calibration in phones solves two problems.
The first one is the hard iron effects (ferromagnetic materials and DC currents in the phone), this would create a bias on each axis. This is obvious, as in the frame of reference of the sensors they do not change.
The second one is finding a matrix $H$ chosen to be symmetric with $\det(H)=1$ to multiply the measurements with to make the amplitude we measure independent of the rotation of the phone. Now, the claim is that the reason we need this matrix $H$ is because of soft iron effects i.e. ferromagnetic objects near the phone (but not on the phone).
Now this claim makes no sense to me for three reasons:

The amplitude of soft iron effects are location dependent not orientation dependent, calibration never gets as an input anything related to location, so it cannot possibly model the soft iron effects.

If it did some how magically made the soft iron effects go away (by finding a nonsymmetric matrix with $\det \neq 1$ that would change $B$ back to $B_e$) then every time we change our location (even a little), we would need to recalibrate the phone.

There is a simpler explanation for why we need $H$. Temperature changes (and other factors) can cause gain changes of the 3 sensors, and stress on the sensors can change their relative alignments. $H$ makes the sensors axis orthogonal and the gains equal; it has nothing to do with soft iron effects, it's just about making the sensors orthonormal.


Am I missing something? Did I misundertood something?

With overwhelming probability, when everyone - including professionals -  except you is wrong YOU are wrong.

@ZeroTheHero So please explain to me where I'm wrong. Objects near the sensors that do not rotate with it, will simply change the perceived amplitude, that's it, no symmetric H with det 1 can help with that.
temperature and stress induced misalignments and gain changes can in fact be solved with a correct H.

@ZeroTheHero Also it's not really a field many people research, what i think happened was that someone notiecd there is a noise in the measurements that can be modeled with this matrix H, they didn't know why so they gave a bs explanation that doesn't make much sense. Then people who don't know better started repeating this wrong explanation everywhere without checking if it's actually correct.  Now maybe I am missing something here, that's why I asked the question.

Re point 3 - phone compasses are notoriously inaccurate, so maybe they should be recalibrated whenever you change location - but this is too much hassle so everyone puts up with an inaccurate compass reading instead.

@gandalf61 etiher way a symetric H will not help with fixing soft iron effects. To fix it youll need to rotate and change amplitude of B_e+soft_lron to B_e. If H is symmetric with det 1 it cannot possibly shrink all apmlitudes or rotate the vectors.

I think your question is ok, but just as advice for the future, phrasing a question as "is everyone else wrong" is a surefire way to turn people against you -- unless you are claiming that you have done the work to prove everyone else is actually wrong and you can back it up with evidence, in which case you had better be sure you are right. Generally you will have a better experience if you phrase a question as "I am confused by X" or "Why do people say X" -- ie, a question, not a challenge.

@Andrew got it, will edit

@ZeroTheHero the more I read about it the more I start to think that not only am I right about soft iron, but that it's not the only misconception about magnometer calibration, setting the matrix det(H)=1 is always explained as "because it preserves volume" which is technically a correct statement but doesn't really explain anything physical about the problem. The real reason for setting the det to 1 is that it's a good enough approximation for keeping the geometric mean of the sensors gains (which is the MLE for multiplicative noise) constant. But that's all it is, an approximation.

I don’t know much about soft iron but unfortunately I know much more about people who claim everybody else is wrong.  First, you just moved the goalpost, as it’s now a matter of understanding an approximation.  How good is this approximation under everyday conditions?  Next, if it’s an approximation, you can be sure there’s published literature on how well it works and correction terms have been computed somewhere.  I will also remark that the source you quote is likely simplifying the situation as it is not necessarily meant to be research-level: there is no peer-reviewed references.

@ZeroTheHero on most sensors this approximatiom is pretty much nearly 100% accurate, this approximation will break when the 3 axis sensors will be very non-orthogonal not something that won't happen in regular magnometers. I don't have a problem with people using det=1, what i have a problem is, with the explanation that seems to be written everywhere. They say we choose det=1 because then it would be volume preserving, while technically correct I don't really see how it explains anything physical about the problem. It's like saying 3 is the first digit of pi because and 3 is 1 more than 2.

@ZeroTheHero okay actually after reading some papers and not blogs I have found people saying that what people call soft iron effects are actually gain changes and misalignments like i said, but then they said that it is still called just soft iron effects because it creates the same effect as soft iron effects. But i still don't see how it creates the same effect. They refrence some other paper which i need to pay to see for this, so thats where my search ends....

@ZeroTheHero okay i think i get it. Given many assumptions if we have a soft iron dipole (assumptioms like being close but not to close, and moving relative to it in acertain way) we can expect to see changes in the field similar to the effects of rotating (not moving) the sensors when it has gain changes and misalignments. So historically it was called the soft iron effects (just a bad name in my opinion). Then poeple in mant forums treat the bad name as an explanatiom without explaining the assumptions and the biggest mechanism for the noise.

@ZeroTheHero it appears to just be a matter of oversimplification combined with bad naming convention leads to a sort of wrong explanation.

@TomerWolberg I can't comment on whether your explanation is correct in this specific case, but that type of situation is VERY common in my experience. It's a sort of epistemological rot... and it also happens with the academic literature.

@MartinC. Yeah makes sense. In this case it was an extreme abuse of notation that caused this wrong explanation to become widespread. If you calibrate a magnometer not by rotating but instead by moving without any rotation and only in very specific cases with a lot of assumptioms the calibration will midigate soft iron effects using the matrix H (but it won't help with hard iron effects in this case) so hystorically they decided to call H the soft iron matrix. However real life calibrations do not change location but instead rotate to compute hard iron and axis orthonormalization not soft iron

@MartinC. I guess the matrix should have been called the "either soft iron or orthonormalization but not both depending on your movement matrix" but they decided to shorten it to soft iron matrix when in 99.9% of use cases it's actually used for orthonormalization of the sensors not for soft iron effects.
